# Uniform and pointwise convergence of function series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

It seems i have issues understanding how to show that certain function series converge. I have done most of the assignment without any issues, but there were two terms that made it very confusing.

$$h_n(x) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, h_n(x) = max\{0,n-n^2|n-\frac{1}{n}|\} $$

In this case it is hard on how to obtain pointwise and uniform convergence out of the $max$ operator. If there are any explanations on this it would be great.

The second one requires only uniform convergence on the interval $[-1,1]$. Though i am rusty on the series convergence criteria. I would require a refresher or a solution to this one as well.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}(1-x^2)^n  $$

I am currently too rusty to solve these problems on my own. I appreciate all the help you can give me.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no $x$ in the definition of $h_n$? Besides, this is not one question. It's a pair of questions.

Comment: Something seems wrong in the definition of $h_n$ since it's $0$ for $n\geq 2$ as written...

Comment: The second one is trivial since $0 \leq (1-x^{2})^{n} \leq 1$.

Comment: I edited it. There was a x in the definition.